# angular 6: prevent router redirect and let server redirect took place

Tags: angular

I have an angular 6 app hosted in *mydomain.com*.

I have set server redirect (302) from *mydomain.com/other* to *myotherdomain.com*.

When I type `mydomain.com/other` instead of redirect to `myotherdomain.com` it redirects back to `mydomain.com`.

I know it's caused by the router that redirect it back to home route.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'prefix' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
```

My question is, is there any way that I can prevent the router to redirect back to home and let the server redirect took place?

Sorry for my bad English.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try to simply remove you wildcard route?

Comment: done that. not succeeded. so i put the wildcard route back.

Comment: Your diagnostic is incorrect. If you type mydomain.com/other in your browser address bar (is that what you're doing?) and hit enter, then the browser sends a GET request to mydomain.com/other . If the server indeed correctly sends back a 302 response, the browser can't possibly start your Angular application: there is nothing in the body of the response, and the browser must make a second GET request to myotherdomain.com and change the location in the address bar.

Comment: Yes. If I open mydomain.com/other first it woks.But if I open mydomain.com first, then mydomain.com/other after, it will back to mydomain.com.

Comment: Define what you mean by "open mydomain.com/other after", precisely. How do you do that? If you do that by clicking on a link using routerLink, then you never send a request to your server, and it thus never responds with a 302. You're just asking the router to change the address in the location bar and to display a different component in the page.

Comment: Open as in write the address mydomain.com/other in address bar